# ruby on rails - Ordering two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models image.rb and story.rb

I am trying to order them together.
stories_controller.rb looks like this:

```
def index
    @stories = Story.all.order(:cached_votes_total => :desc)
    @images = Image.all.order(:cached_votes_total => :desc)
    @combined = (@stories + @images).sort_by {|record| record.created_at}
end


private
    def story_params
        params.require(:story).permit(:title, :content, :category)
    end
```

images_controller.rb looks like this:

```
private
    def image_params
        params.require(:image).permit(:title, :image, :image_file_name, :category)
    end
```

In my index.html.erb im tryign to order them both but i run into undefined method errors because they have different parameters.

```
<% @combined.each do |s| %>
    ...        
<% end %>
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is an wrong approach, you should use model association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an wrong approach, combining two models is not recommended, you should use model association for this.. For example

```
#  Image Model
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :story
end

#  Image Model
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image
end
```

**In the controller..**

```
def index
    @stories = Story.find(:all, :include => :image).order(:cached_votes_total => :desc)
end
```

**and finally in the view**

```
<% @stories.each do |story| %>

# here you can access story and story.image
    ...        
<% end %>
```

Comment: So in my migration I have create_stories and create_images, so I should add create_table :images to the create_stories migration file? since this now returns Unknown column 'images.story_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`story_id` IN ('7', '8')

Comment: Learn about associations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html